# Database Architecture Question

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL Database that I am going to be interacting with via LINQ once built. 
It has a client who has (ignoring the others) two fkID fields to two tables.

> Class
>     Country

What I am trying to do is store a "Rules" table where the following happens:

```
if the Class is 'A' and the Country is 'USA' then 
    create rows  'RowsA' in table todo

else if the class is 'A' and the country is not 'USA' then
    create rows 'RowsB'  in table todo

else
    create rows 'RowsC' in table todo
```

So, is the best way to do this to have in the rules table

> RuleID Identity
>  ClassFK   Int
>   null
>  CountryFK  Int null
>  order
>   int not null

and have my C# code do the following:

```
var rules = from r in db.Rules
            orderby r.order
            select r;

foreach(rule in rules)
{
     if (((client.ClassFK == rule.ClassFK) || (rule.ClassFK == null)) &&             
           ((client.CountryFK== rule.CountryFK) || (rule.CountryFK== null)))
     {
          // Create The Rows
     }
}
```

This seems awfully flimsy to me

Comment: How about using TRIGGER? Pros/cons: less transparent to application code.

Comment: I would suggest not using a trigger. I don't think I have come across a valid reason to use a trigger yet unless you want to confuse the next programmer trying to debug your code.

Comment: Kelsey, Lots of good reasons to use triggers if your developers know what they are doing. Complex data integrity rules must alwawys be ina trigger. Handling them in the application becasue the developers don't understand database development is at best irresponsible (there are other ways data gets into the the database thanthe application!) and at worst harmful to the bottom line of the company. Data integrity should trump developer incompetence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it a little cleaner looking I think would be to make a method on the Rule class that checks whether it applies to a client or not; That makes your code look something like:

```
foreach(rule in rules.Where(r => r.AppliesTo(client)))
{
    // Create the Rows
}
```

However, the part I see missing is knowing what rows to create based on a particular rule; This is not contained in your rules table.